# How to create/add middleware that adds default headers to each request

Tags: dart, cors, dart-io, dart-shelf

How can I add middleware to the shelf pipeline that adds default HTTP headers to each request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Update

There is now a pub package to simplify adding CORS headers
see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_cors

#### Original

See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/cloud/2Vn_IqzGtTc

```dart
final Map<String, String> _headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                      'Content-Type': 'text/html'};

// for OPTIONS (preflight) requests just add headers and an empty response
shelf.Response _options(shelf.Request request) => (request.method == 'OPTIONS') ?
    new shelf.Response.ok(null, headers: _headers) : null;

shelf.Response _cors(shelf.Response response) => response.change(headers: _headers);

shelf.Middleware _fixCORS = shelf.createMiddleware(
    requestHandler: _options, responseHandler: _cors);

final shelf.Handler handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
  .addMiddleware(_fixCORS)
  .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
  .addMiddleware(exceptionResponse())
  .addHandler(routes.handler);
```

See also http://thomaslockerambling.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/shelf-middleware-adding-cors-headers.html

Comment: Ah. I'm trying to implement simple webserver with shelf. it's a bit challenge :(

Comment: Yeah, I had lot of troubles too. I got most things I needed working but can't claim to understand why ;-)

Comment: shelf_cors 0.2.1 => Dart 2 Incompatible