# Making POST with Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to do a POST with DART and I'm getting this error, for now I just want to print the message on server side to be sure that I'm receiving it, but I don't know how to interpretate the error:

- in Server Side:

> [WARNING] rpc:
>   Response
>     Status Code: 500
>     Headers:
>       access-control-allow-credentials: true
>       access-control-allow-origin: *
>       cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>       content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>       expires: 0
>       pragma: no-cache
>     Exception:
>       RPC Error with status: 500 and message: Invalid argument(s)

- in Client Side:
  [image]

At my client side in DART I have this code:

```
async.Future<core.List> loadFiles(heatMapMessages request){

  var _url=null;
  var _queryParams = new core.Map();
  var _uploadMedia = null;
  var _uploadOptions = null;
  var _downloadOptions = commons.DownloadOptions.Metadata;
  var _body = null;

  if (request != null) {
    _body = convert.JSON.encode(converterClass.toJson(request));
  }

  _url = "load";
  var _response = _requester.request(_url, "POST",
    body: _body,
    queryParams: _queryParams,
    uploadOptions: _uploadOptions,
    uploadMedia: _uploadMedia,
    downloadOptions: _downloadOptions);

  return _response.then((data) => converterClass.fromJson(data));
}
```

And receiving it on my server Side as:

```
  @ApiMethod(method: 'POST', path: 'load')
  Future<List<String>> loadFiles(heatMapMessages filename1) async{
    print("test "+filename1.jsonInfo);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `POST` request to a different domain than where your client application was initially loaded from, the browser sends a preflight request (request type `OPTION`). Your server needs to handle it and respond properly otherwise the browser won't make the actual `POST` request.

[How to create/add middleware that adds default headers to each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253389/how-to-create-add-middleware-that-adds-default-headers-to-each-request) shows how to do it using the [shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf) package.

You see that if the request method is `OPTIONS` it responds with headers

```
{
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'text/html'
}
```

Additional header parameters might be necessary depending on what you try to do.